# Does the following snippet define FPS or the number of frames after which the image should move?

Tags: c, animation, sdl, sdl-2

Here's a snippet of code from a series of articles that I am learning SDL from:

```
double image_x = 0.0;
SDL_Rect image_position;
main () {
  // Code to load a BMP file
  // and blit the corresponding image-surface onto the window-surface
  // with the destination position on window-surface defined by image_position.
  while (game_is_running) { // Game loop
    while (event_present) { // Event loop
     // Logic
    }
    update(1.0/60.0);
  }
}

void update (double delta_time) {
  image_x = image_x + (5 * delta_time);
  image_position.x = image_x;
  draw();
}
```

For better context, in the particular tutorial, the author explains how to load a BMP file and then blit it onto the window surface. We then animate the image such that it moves across the screen but we want to do it in a controlled manner.

`image_position` is a simple `SDL_Rect` which will define where the image will be placed on the window surface. It will be used as the last argument to SDL_BlitSurface when drawing to the screen as follows:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(image_surface, NULL, window_surface, &image_position);
```

The function `draw` (not shown in code) is supposed to clear the screen and draw the image onto the screen at the X and Y specified by `image_position`.

The function `update` is supposed to update the position of the image and then update the screen.

**My question:**

In the article the author states that passing `1.0/60.0` to the function `update`

> capped the frame rate to 60fps.

Based on the code, I think this is wrong. The `update` function only increases x-position of the image every 60 frames or so. This is NOT the same as frames-per-second because in FPS, there is an element of time involved while in the `update` function there is no time involved. So, is the author actually right in his statement? Or was my understanding of the code correct?

To those interested in the article series: https://dev.to/noah11012/using-sdl2-scaling-and-moving-an-image-pj

**Note:** This post is solely meant to verify my understanding of the code. This post is not meant to harm the original author's reputation in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's wrong. `update` will increase `image_x` with the same amount every time, no matter how long time that has passed since the last call. It's not connected to FPS at all.

`update(double delta_time)` is supposed to get called with the time that has passed since last time the screen was drawn.
`image_x = image_x + (5 * delta_time);` will then make `image_x` increase more on a slower machine than on a faster one.

When you call it with a hardcoded value, like `1.0 / 60.0` you effectively undo the whole purpose of using a function like that, which is there to give you the highest FPS that your system can handle.

What you should be doing is something like this:

```c
  double prev_time = get_time_as_double();
  while (game_is_running) { // Game loop
    while (event_present) { // Event loop
     // Logic
    }
    double new_time = get_time_as_double();
    update(new_time - prev_time); // calculate the time that has passed
    prev_time = new_time;
  }
```

`get_time_as_double()` can be implemented by calling [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) on Posix systems. If you are using a non-Posix OS, find a function that provides a steady clock with reasonably high resolution.

Example:

```
double get_time_as_double() {
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return ts.tv_sec + ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
}
```